# Pandas - assign selected columns back to original dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

These are the datatypes of my dataframe:

```
Out[172]: 
price                   float64
host_response_rate      float64
host_acceptance_rate    float64
host_is_superhost        object
host_listings_count     float64
zipcode                  object
property_type            object
room_type                object
accommodates              int64
bathrooms               float64
bedrooms                float64
beds                    float64
bed_type                 object
amenities                object
number_of_reviews         int64
review_scores_rating    float64
cancellation_policy      object
reviews_per_month       float64
city                     object
dtype: object
```

I want to scale all numeric values, which I do with the following code:

```
pd.DataFrame(scaler.fit_transform(df.select_dtypes("float64").to_numpy()), columns = df.select_dtypes("float64").columns)
```

I struggle how to find out how to assign the correct column to the original column in a dynamic way. I tried this and it does not work because I call a function:

```
df.select_dtypes("float64") = pd.DataFrame(scaler.fit_transform(df.select_dtypes("float64").to_numpy()), columns = df.select_dtypes("float64").columns)
```

How can I assign every column back to its original dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
df.loc[:,df.dtypes=='float64'] = scaler.fit_transform(df.select_dtypes('float64'))
```

or

```
df.loc[:,df.dtypes=='float64'] = scaler.fit_transform(df.loc[:,df.dtypes=='float64'])
```